# With Meteor's iron-router, how do you re-render the template from a template event?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My template shows different content based on a non-reactive value (in localStorage). I would like to do the following:

```
Template.foo.events
  'click #link': ->
    localStorage.setItem 'key', 'different'
    // re-render template foo
```

`this.render()` is undefined. `Router.render('foo')` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a dependency tied to your value.

```
keyDep = new Deps.Dependency()

Template.foo.events
  'click #link': ->
    localStorage.setItem 'key', 'different'
    keyDep.changed()

Template.foo.key = ->
  keyDep.depend()
  return localStorage.getItem 'key'
```